# How to Disable Particular Cells in Telerik GridView Row

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, telerik

Hi I am having a **telerik GridView** in my WPF application. In that grid i am having three columns like **Number, Max** and **Min**. Now I need to **disable** the **Min** and **Max** Cells When i will give some value on the Number column for a selected row.

I declared two variables like **MaxCell** and **MinCell** as GridViewCellBase. If The Query(Mentioned below for Getting MaxCell and MinCell) will return null value, I am not able to give **IsEnabled** as **False**. Its not accepting any value . Its giving **Null reference Exception**. 
   How can i solve this problem ? can any Please tell me the solution of this problem? Thanks in Advance.

```
       foreach (GridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
         {
             if (cell.Column.Header.ToString() == "Number" && Convert.ToInt32  (cell.Value) > 0)
             {
                 GridViewCellBase MaxCell = new GridViewCellBase();
                 GridViewCellBase MinCell=new GridViewCellBase();
                 MaxCell=(from c in row.Cells
                                    where c.Column.Name == "Max"
                                    select c).FirstOrDefault();
                 MinCell =(from c in row.Cells
                                     where c.Column.Name == "Min"
                                     select c).FirstOrDefault();

                 MaxCell.IsEnabled = false;// Here I am getting the null reference  exception when MaxCell and MinCell having empty values


                 MinCell.IsEnabled = false; 
                 break;
             }


         }
```

The **MaxCell** always returning empty value only. So i cant give the **IsEnabled** property. Now my doubt is, Why the MaxCell value is always coming as empty or null value? The cells are having the column like **"Max"** and **"Min"**. Then it should return the **Actual Cell** but Why its always returning null value?

Comment: Not sure if i understand your question but can't you not check is `MaxCell` is null or not and then access the properties, coz `FirstOrDefault` would return null if not found

Comment: It always returning empty value only. If i check that MaxCell,it is null or not it will come out from my loop. So i cant give the is enabled property. Now my doubt is, Why the MaxCell value is always coming as empty or null value? The cells are having the column like "Max" and "Min". then Why its always returning null value?

Comment: well you are already looping across cells so probably only one cell might satisfy the condition while for the others it would return null, when you are already looping through cells then why the select ?

Comment: Thanks. actually My need is, When i give some int value on the Number column then the Max and Min columns in the same row should get disabled not the full columns only row should be disabled... There are three different columns in the same row Thats why i tried like this... Can you please let me know the correct way to acheive this? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using approach you've described. I would try modifying cell style of particular columns and create a binding on IsEnabled property with converter that is returning appropriate value.

```
<Style x:Key="MinMaxCellStyle" TargetType="{x:Type GridView:GridViewCell}">                        
      <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding Normal, Converter{StaticResources NormalToEnabledConverter}" />
</Style>
```

Then Apply this style to specific columns as fallows:

```
<GridView:GridViewDataColumn CellStyle="{StaticResource MinMaxCellStyle}" />
```

If you don't like this you can always use triggers.